# Android Firebase: Record Robo Script failed to access data folder

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

When launching a robotest for my app, my sql fails to build a database:

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Couldn't mkdirs /data/user/0/com.gazman.beep/databases/db4
```

I tried both with real device and Android Studio emulator.
I also used `adb shell: run-as` command to access the data folder and see what directories been created with regular runs.

And I found that `/data/user/0/com.gazman.beep/databases/db4` was there as expected.

Can you think of any way that I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

For specific issues like this, I would recommend asking on the official Slack channel (firebase-community.slack.com, #test-lab), since the Firebase Test Lab eng team can directly look at your test runs. There are also other users that may have run into the same issues as you.